# How to catch keyboard event in content editable table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have an HTML table which :

- Contains editable cells
- Rowspans

In the content editable cells, it is possible to press 'Enter' key in the keyboard which doesn't make any sense in case if I want to allow users just to input **single line data**.

What I want is when users press enter button on an editable cell it  should focus onto the nearest editable cell (right/down) for new input.

How should I approach to solve the problem?

```html
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Data 1</th>
      <th>Data 2</th>
      <th>Data 3</th>
      <th>Data 4</th>
      <th>Data 5</th>
      <th>Data 6</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" contenteditable="true"><label><input type="radio" name="typeOf0" checked=""> <span>Radio 1</span> </label><br><label><input type="radio" name="typeOf0"> <span>Radio 2</span> </label><br></td>
      <td rowspan="3" contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td rowspan="3" contenteditable="true">0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
      <td contenteditable="true">0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr></tr>
   <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There are multiple solutions on codepen, like this one made with jQuery: https://codepen.io/josheinstein/pen/jifqx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to catch keydowns, and handle the enter (key code 13).

You can edit the already provided example from @filemono to allow it to work with enter.

```
(function ($) {

  $.fn.enableCellNavigation = function () {

    var keys = {
      left: 37,
      up: 38,
      right: 39,
      down: 40,
      enter: 13
    };

    // select all on focus
    // works for input elements, and will put focus into
    // adjacent input or textarea. once in a textarea,
    // however, it will not attempt to break out because
    // that just seems too messy imho.
    this.find('input').keydown(function (e) {

      // shortcut for key other than arrow keys
      if ($.inArray(e.which, [keys.left, keys.up, keys.right, keys.down, keys.enter]) < 0) {
        return;
      }

      var input = e.target;
      var td = $(e.target).closest('td');
      var moveTo = null;

      switch (e.which) {

        case keys.left:
          {
            if (input.selectionStart == 0) {
              moveTo = td.prev('td:has(input,textarea)');
            }
            break;
          }
        case keys.right:
          {
            if (input.selectionEnd == input.value.length) {
              moveTo = td.next('td:has(input,textarea)');
            }
            break;
          }

        case keys.up:
        case keys.enter:
        case keys.down:
          {

            var tr = td.closest('tr');
            var pos = td[0].cellIndex;

            var moveToRow = null;
            if (e.which == keys.down || e.which == keys.enter) {
              moveToRow = tr.next('tr');
            } else if (e.which == keys.up) {
              moveToRow = tr.prev('tr');
            }

            if (moveToRow.length) {
              moveTo = $(moveToRow[0].cells[pos]);
            }

            break;
          }

      }

      if (moveTo && moveTo.length) {

        e.preventDefault();

        moveTo.find('input,textarea').each(function (i, input) {
          input.focus();
          input.select();
        });

      }

    });

  };

})(jQuery);


// use the plugin
$(function () {
  $('#people').enableCellNavigation();
});
```